# Excel VBA .Find failing sporadically

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 toggle buttons on a work sheet, 4 that are use to pull partial data from another worksheet and a 5th that pulls all the data from the other worksheet. It's a simple function, if you click any of the 4 partial data toggles they turn the all data toggle false and then run the sub "SearchData" while passing it a variable. There is no issues with any of these. The 5th, all data toggle though works fine when the other 4 toggle false statement are commented out. When I uncomment the 4 statement so that it turns the other 4 toggle false it causes the called sub  "SearchData" to fail. The failing portion of the call sub is below. The `.Find` does nothing and all values come back as `""` giving me a `Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`. Now if all 4 partial data toggle are already false it runs fine. It only happen when one or more of the 4 partial data toggles are true and I turn to all data toggle true.

```
Private Sub TbAllOpen_Click()

    If TbAllOpen.value = True Then
        TbAllOpen.BackColor = &HFF00&
'        TbOpenEst.value = False
'        TbOpenInv.value = False
'        TbReceivables.value = False
'        TbUnsuc.value = False
        CurrentStatus = "All"
        SearchData CurrentStatus
    Else
        TbAllOpen.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TbOpenEst_Click()

    If TbOpenEst.value = True Then
        TbOpenEst.BackColor = &HFF00&
        TbAllOpen.value = False
        CurrentStatus = "Quote"
        SearchData CurrentStatus
    Else
        TbOpenEst.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
    End If
    
    SendKeys ("{ESC}")

End Sub

Private Sub TbOpenInv_Click()

    If TbOpenInv.value = True Then
        TbOpenInv.BackColor = &HFF00&
        TbAllOpen.value = False
        CurrentStatus = "Complete"
        SearchData CurrentStatus
    Else
        TbOpenInv.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
    End If
    
    SendKeys ("{ESC}")

End Sub

Private Sub TbReceivables_Click()

    If TbReceivables.value = True Then
        TbReceivables.BackColor = &HFF00&
        TbAllOpen.value = False
        CurrentStatus = "Work Order"
        SearchData CurrentStatus
    Else
        TbReceivables.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
    End If
    
    SendKeys ("{ESC}")

End Sub

Private Sub TbUnsuc_Click()

    If TbUnsuc.value = True Then
        TbUnsuc.BackColor = &HFF00&
        TbAllOpen.value = False
        CurrentStatus = "Unsuccessful"
        SearchData CurrentStatus
    Else
        TbUnsuc.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
    End If
    
    SendKeys ("{ESC}")

End Sub
```

This is the section that fails in the called sub

```
Dim L as Long

L = Ws1.Cells(1, Ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With Ws1.Range("A1", Ws1.Cells(1, L))

    Dim FindResult As Range
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("Active", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        Fld2 = FindResult.Column
    End If

    Set FindResult = .Find("Date", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        Fld3 = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("Status", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        Fld6 = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("generated_job_id", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        Fld10 = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("payment_amount", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        Fld16 = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("total_invoice_amount", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        Fld36 = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
    Set FindResult = .Find("category_uuid", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not FindResult Is Nothing Then
        Fld38 = FindResult.Column
    End If
    
End With
```

Comment: Where and how are `Fld2` declared?  Which exact line fails?  You set those values when a Find succeeds, but do you ever need to *unset* them?

Comment: They are declared at the beginning of the called sub `as Long` and all 7 fail `Fld2 - Fld38`. As to when they fail it is only with a exact set of conditions. One or more of the four partial data toggles is true and the all data toggle being turned to true. I have ran the code hundreds of time and with any other combination it has never failed, only with this exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work correctly so I completely revamped my whole process. I now create the CurrentStatus variable inside the called sub instead of passing it to the sub taking it out of the toggle buttons completely. I inserted a worksheet level variable `z` and in each of the toggle buttons installed a exit sub procedure. Each toggle button now sets the `z` as needed, transitions the other toggles and then clears `z`. This insures that the called sub `SearchData` is only run once and not from each toggle that changes value.

```
Private Sub TbAllOpen_Click()

    If z = 1 Then
        TbAllOpen.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TbAllOpen.value = True Then
        TbAllOpen.BackColor = &HFF00&
        z = 1
        TbOpenEst.value = False
        TbOpenInv.value = False
        TbReceivables.value = False
        TbUnsuc.value = False
        z = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M2").value = "True"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M3").value = "True"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M4").value = "True"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M5").value = "True"
    Else
        TbAllOpen.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M2").value = "False"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M3").value = "False"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M4").value = "False"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M5").value = "False"
    End If

SearchData

End Sub

Private Sub TbOpenEst_Click()

    If z = 1 Then
        TbOpenEst.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TbOpenEst.value = True Then
        If TbAllOpen.value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M2").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M3").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M4").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M5").value = "False"
        End If
        TbOpenEst.BackColor = &HFF00&
        z = 1
        TbAllOpen.value = False
        z = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M2").value = "True"
    Else
        TbOpenEst.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M2").value = "False"
    End If

SearchData

End Sub

Private Sub TbOpenInv_Click()

    If z = 1 Then
        TbOpenInv.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TbOpenInv.value = True Then
        If TbAllOpen.value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M2").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M3").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M4").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M5").value = "False"
        End If
        TbOpenInv.BackColor = &HFF00&
        z = 1
        TbAllOpen.value = False
        z = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M4").value = "True"
    Else
        TbOpenInv.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M4").value = "False"
    End If

SearchData

End Sub

Private Sub TbReceivables_Click()

    If z = 1 Then
        TbReceivables.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TbReceivables.value = True Then
        If TbAllOpen.value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M2").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M3").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M4").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M5").value = "False"
        End If
        TbReceivables.BackColor = &HFF00&
        z = 1
        TbAllOpen.value = False
        z = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M3").value = "True"
    Else
        TbReceivables.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M3").value = "False"
    End If

SearchData

End Sub

Private Sub TbUnsuc_Click()

    If z = 1 Then
        TbUnsuc.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TbUnsuc.value = True Then
        If TbAllOpen.value = True Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M2").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M3").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M4").value = "False"
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M5").value = "False"
        End If
        TbUnsuc.BackColor = &HFF00&
        z = 1
        TbAllOpen.value = False
        z = 0
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M5").value = "True"
    Else
        TbUnsuc.BackColor = &HFFE1C8
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Formatting").Range("M5").value = "False"
    End If

SearchData

End Sub
```